# How to add the Extra Initialization Command through command prompt

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet

I know that we can add `Extra Initialization Command` from Modem Properties and Advanced tab. BUT

Is there any way to add the `Extra Initialization Command` through command prompt ?

Where this `Extra Initialization Command` is stored ? is it stored in registry or somewhere else ?

Comment: to give you a start, modem init strings are stored in the registry, like millions of other settings :-)
**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet \Services \Class \Modem \0000 \Init **
BUT it is not always at this exact location, there can be more than one modem, etc. You should look manually in that area and find the modem in use.  .
A registry entry can be silently added to the registry with a simple batch file. If it was ME, I would make the settings I wanted IN the GUI, then EXPORT the registry section.  Then at any time you can re-import the registry.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that both on Windows XP and 7 it is stored in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{4D36E96D-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0000\UserInit` (as a string).

If you have multiple modems set up on your machine, the last folder will be incremented (for instance ...\0001\UserInit

From there you edit it with reg.exe:

This will display value:

> reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class{4D36E96D-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0000 /v UserInit

This allows you to replace the current value (edit):

> reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class{4D36E96D-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0000 /v UserInit /t REG_SZ /d "AT+CGTCOND" /f

Note that on Windows 7, executing this as standard user only allows you to read value, and not to edit it.

More infos on reg command here: http://www.petri.co.il/reg_command_in_windows_xp.htm